# Pgpool executes queries on standby nodes instead of master when replication is behind in standby

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I have a postgresql 10 master db with 2 hot standby servers with streaming replication, and the replication is working correctly. The `synchronous_commit` is setted to `remote_write`

Also I have a pgpool 3.7.5 configured with the params:

```
delay_threshold = 1
sr_check_period = 1
```

And the the following weights:

- master: 1
- node1: 3
- node2: 3

In the log I can see the node1 and node2 are lagging:

```
Replication of node:1 is behind 75016 bytes from the primary server (node:0)
```

The [pgpool docs](http://www.pgpool.net/docs/pgpool-II-3.7.5/en/html/runtime-streaming-replication-check.html) says:

> delay_threshold (integer)
>
> Specifies the maximum tolerance level of replication delay in WAL bytes on the standby server against the primary server. If the delay exceeds this configured level, Pgpool-II stops sending the SELECT queries to the standby server and starts routing everything to the primary server even if load_balance_mode is enabled, until the standby catches-up with the primary. Setting this parameter to 0 disables the delay checking. This delay threshold check is performed every sr_check_period. Default is 0.

The problem it's that pgpool sends queries to the hot standbys before they obtained the new data from master through streaming replication.

I enabled the `log_per_node_statement = on` temporally to be able to see which node the query executes and I can see that queries are sent to the nodes even if there aren't sync when `delay_threshold` should avoid that.

Am I missing something? When the nodes are behind master the queries are not supposed to go the master?

Thanks in advance.

Other config values of pgpool are:

```
num_init_children = 120
max_pool = 3
connection_cache = off
load_balance_mode = on
master_slave_sub_mode = 'stream'
replication_mode = off
sr_check_period = 1
```